# From where can I get Mrtyunjaya Tantra / Mrtyu-Sanjaya Tantra book?

Tags: scripture, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, tantra, gaudiya-vaishnavism

Pranam! I am looking for above mentioned book named as Mrtyunjaya Tantra which is mentioned by Srila Jiva Goswami in his Krishna Sandarba and also mentioned by many scholars somewhere. It is one of the Vaishnava Tantra book and it contains the description of Spiritual World. I have contacted many libraries but I haven't found it yet. If someone can get this book then it would be great help for me and for society.

Comment: Don't know about any such tantra. There is netra tantra which is called mrityujit as it makes one capable of conquering death. And it is shaiva tantra.

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed all the Vaishnava tantras seem to disappear? I am sure they are all hidden somewhere they just aren't getting published and disseminated. This covert hiddenness of the Vaishnava is very suspect. It is clear thst the Six Goswamis of Brindavan were privy to and had access to Vaishnava tantric material. An independent study should be conducted into this.

Comment: Do you have an answer to the actual question?